# How do I boot to terminal - cannot start 23.04 on Hyper-V?

Tags: boot, command-line, grub2, 23.04

I have just updated two 22.10 VMs to 23.04.  Both VMs reported completing successfully, but I can only access one of them. With the other one the GUI is not accessible. This is noted here as a but with a possible workaround.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-desktop-installer/+bug/2016444, however to run this I need to be able to login (neither telnet or SSH are available).

When the VM starts the bootloader I can see boot options to either edit the boot commands or to go to a grub prompt, but I don't know how to use these to boot into terminal mode, so I can make the necessary changes to the VM.

boot options:

[image: boot options]

boot commands:

[image: boot commands]